How to implement the most basic use of Google reCaptcha v3
I am running a Wordpress site and want to protect a custom contact form with Googles reCaptcha v3.
Sadly my code seems to be wrong and I couldnt find the problem, please help.
This is my Form
<?php
 // reCAPTCHA v3
 define('SITE_KEY', 'Key');
 define('SECRET_KEY', 'SCRT_KEY');

 echo '<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=' . SITE_KEY . '"></script>';
?>

<form action="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/sent" method="POST" id="footer-form">

 <!--INPUT FIELDS HERE-->
 <input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" />

 <button class="button_1" type="submit">
  Send
 </button>

</form>

<script>
 grecaptcha.ready(function() {
  grecaptcha.execute("KEY IS HERE", {action: "homepage"})
  .then(function(token) {
   console.log(token);
   document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value=token;
  });
 });
</script>

My form posts to this php file
// reCAPTCHA v3
define('SITE_KEY', 'KEY');
define('SECRET_KEY', 'SCRT_KEY');

$Response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response={$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']}");
$Return = json_decode($Response);

if($Return->success == true && $Return->score > 0.5){
 EMAIL CODE HERE
}

thats about it..
first part seems to work because my g-recaptcha field value got the session token
but the $Response is always false ( i think file_get_contents doesnt work?)
I hope someone can help me, also I dont want to use a PlugIn. Thanks
This code is adapted from this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/61QBrGpwQGg?si=TU3BUsN1RXN9jpmq
This guy had the same problem, but no solution:
Google recaptcha v3 success issue

You should probably use cURL instead of file_get_contents, it's more configurable and reliable

@aynber I sadly dont think thats really it.. wanna stick to basic php

Using PHP's cURL implementation is still basic PHP. It's more portable, since some servers have allow_url_fopen disabled., which would prevent file_get_contents from fetching URL data.

file_get_contents used with HTTP URLs will return false, if the HTTP status code of the response is indicating an error. You would need to pass in an HTTP stream context with ignore_errors set to true, to get access to the response body in this case.

And file_get_contents with an HTTP URL will use request method GET - but the verify endpoint requires a POST request. You can use file_get_contents to make POST requests, but that also requires an HTTP stream context, explicitly specifying which method to use.

The problem was that file_get_contents() had missing context...
Google Api only accepts POST requests. Needed stream_context_create()...
